# Boolean operators while searching in Less?

Tags: less-unix

I'm reading file using Less. I need to search for some text, but I would like to exclude some other text.

Is it possible to build expressions like

*/someText OR another text*

or its not supported ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions in less search.

```
/some text|another text
```